# Correctly redirect a folder/directory to an external URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've found loads of different variations all over the internet and am wanting to find the correct / propper way of redirecting from: `example.com/folder/` to `test.com/read/old/data/main.php?ac=21323`

Some websites/guides put the following at the start:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews ## No idea...
RewriteEngine On  ## Turns "mod_rewrite" on
RewriteBase / ## No idea...
```

Are theses necessary and what do they all do; I assume the rewrite engine on is 100% needed for it to function correctly.

Some of the rewrite rulles start of with: `^(.*)$` some start of with `^(/)$` what ones if any are correct?

Some of the URL's end with `/$1` and some don't end with it...

Some end with: `[L,R=301,NC]` and some end with `[L,R=301]` again which ones are correct (if any)?

**Downvotes and no help, reasoning or anything... wow guys**

Comment: You can check [this cheatsheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) to get an understanding of how regex meta characters work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way to redirect the link is by using

```
Redirect 301 example.com/folder/ test.com/read/old/data/main.php?ac=21323
```

Redirect is faster than RedirectMatch and RewriteRule. Above rule will permanently(301) redirect the link.

L = means if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed.

R = Redirect (301 = Permanent, 302 = Temporary)

NC = (No Case) case-insensitive

^(.*)$ = match everything

---

### **RewriteRule [Pattern] [Substitution] [Flags]**

```
RewriteRule ^/product/(.*)/view$ /product-page2/$1
```

Any **(.*) in Pattern** will be available as **$1, $2, $3 in Substitution** , In above example we have used only one (. *) so only $1 available. If we used more than one then we can use $2 and so on as below example.

```
RewriteRule ^/product/(.*)/(.*)/view$ /product-page2/$1/$2
```

For $1 and other you can check this page
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html#InternalBackRefs

Comment: So if I wanted to redirect from `test.com/redir/folder` to `website.com` I would put: `RewriteRule ^(folder)$ http://www.website.com/ [R=301,L,NC]` With $ on wildcarded domains? or `RewriteRule ^(folder) http://www.website.com/ [R=301,L,NC]` Without $ on wildcarded domains? or would I put: `RewriteRule http://test.com/redir/folder http://www.website.com/ [R=301,L,NC]`

Comment: you can simply do this. `Redirect 301 http://test.com/redir/folder http://website.com` and also check this [link](http://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection)

Answer (score 1):

Kinda bumbling through this myself :-)
RE: Some of the rewrite rulles start of with: ^(.*)$ some start of with ^(/)$ what ones if any are correct?

Some of the URL's end with /$1 and some don't end with it...

Some end with: [L,R=301,NC] and some end with [L,R=301] again which ones are correct (if any)?

Take a look at http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs

Search the page for Code explanation

You probably already checked it out but also take a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

RE: Downvotes and no help, reasoning or anything... wow guys

Get used to it :-) It's the kind of thing that made me quit asking questions on the site